# When can I replace concurrent collection with standard collection?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, concurrency

When I have several threads that need to work concurrently with a a collection, I usually use the collections under `System.Collections.Concurrent`.
However, these collections are more expensive compared to their non-concurrent counterparts. I wonder if I could, in certain cases, safely replace them by non concurrent collections.

For example, suppose I have a Dictionary which I first fill up with data, and later on I spawn several threads (or tasks) which only *read* from it, or only check if a key exists, but never write or change it.

In such scenario, would it be safe to use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, or do I still have to use `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`?

And in the general case, can I assume all standard collections support multiple readers as long as the collection is not modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example, suppose I have a Dictionary which I first fill up with data, and later on I spawn several threads (or tasks) which only read from it, or only check if a key exists, but never write or change it.

Yes, it's safe to *read* from a `Dictionary<,>` from multiple threads, so long as there are *no* writers. You should make sure there's a memory barrier between the last write and the first read - but if you're spawning the threads *after* populating the dictionary, that shouldn't be an issue.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> A `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified.

Comment: Is it a general rule for all collections, that we can have multiple concurrent readers as long as we don't modify the collection? Or is this a special property of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`?

Comment: @AmirGonnen: It's at least very common. It's worth checking, but the most common collections in .NET have that property.

Comment: Ok, let's take `HashSet<T>` for example. The documentation says nothing about it. Does it make sense to assume it works like `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and concurrent readers are allowed?

Comment: @AmirGonnen: Yes, I think that's a reasonable assumption.